# PHPMAKER, how to creat view mysql

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

I have name a table named "hitung" with columns

- ID primarykey
- BM int
- BR int
- BK int

I've created a view table. My code is as following

```
SELECT hitung.ID AS ID ((hitung.BM + hitung.BR)-hitung.BK) AS Total From hitung WHERE hitung.ID = hitung.ID
```

when I insert into the table following data

- BM 10
- BR 5
- BK 1

the column "total" doesn't show anything

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but your query can be simplified

```
SELECT `ID`, (`BM` + `BR` - `BK`) AS `Total` 
FROM `hitung`
```

For example WHERE condition looks weird.

If you want to create SQL view from this query then you need execute the following

```
 CREATE VIEW `test` AS
 SELECT `ID`, (BM + BR - BK) AS `Total` 
 FROM `hitung`
```

and after this command

```
SELECT * FROM `test`
```

It will show the view with total column

Comment: does this post answer your question?